# Gradle doesn't notice changes made to build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

In my android app, I added some dependencies for spring. These resulted in sync errors. When I removed those dependencies from the build.gradle file and synced again I get the same errors. Why does Gradle still act like those dependencies are there when I clearly removed them? I re-synced about 10 times, did a gradlew clean and tried running with --refresh-dependencies. Am I missing something? I'm pretty new to Gradle so...

update:
After re-opening IntelliJ 2 times. It noticed the changes and synced successfully.

update2:
The issue was I think as CrazyCoder said: I probably updated the file while the Gradle daemon was running.

Comment: It could be that the Gradle daemon was still running with the old build file.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yep.... just came to me a second ago.